# Windows 7 Python installation: Works with full command, but "file.py --version" returns "Could not load Python dll"

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

*This is a followup to this question: [The *only* way to successfully execute Django python command is with "python ...PATH...django-admin.py [options]". Why can't it be reduced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069236/the-only-way-to-successfully-execute-django-python-command-is-with-python)*

I can successfully run a command, say `django-admin.py`, as long as I prefix it with ***both*** `python` and the fully-qualified path to the py file. For example, this works fine:

`python c:\applications\programming\python_341\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite`

But none of the following work (see the previous question for specific responses):

- `django-admin.py startproject mysite`
- `python django-admin.py startproject mysite`
- `c:\applications\programming\python_341\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite`

Most concerning is when I run, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069236/the-only-way-to-successfully-execute-django-python-command-is-with-python#comment39001530_25069236), this:

```
django-admin.py --version
```

It responds with

```
Could not load Python dll
```

I honestly don't know what it's supposed to respond with, but I'm guessing this ain't it.

I've uninstalled, restarted my computer, and reinstalled Python (as well as everything listed by `pip freeze`) *three times* today.

Is this something I need to worry about? What can I do to fix it?

FYI: Starting the Python shell prints this at the top:

`Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

---

Updated PATH, after following @Bo102010's suggestion:

```
C:\applications\programming\python_341\DLLs;
C:\applications\programming\python_341\;
C:\applications\programming\python_341\Scripts;
C:\applications\programming\;
.;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\ArcSoft\Bin;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\applications\programming\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin;
C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;
C:\applications\programming\jdk_7_51\bin;
C:\applications\video\quicktime\QTSystem\;
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;
C:\applications\programming\apache-maven-3.2.2\bin;
C:\applications\utilities\gpg4win\pub
```

---

> If you search your drives for django-admin.py do you just find the one? –  Bo102010

`C:\applications\programming\python_341\Scripts\django-admin.py` (this is the one on the PATH. This one has a windows path in the source code, the other has a unix/linux path):

```
#!C:\applications\programming\python_341\python.exe
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

`C:\applications\programming\python_341\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

I confirmed that both of these files are installed by Django. I uninstalled and both disappeared.

Comment: What do you get if you run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path);"` ?

Comment: @Bo102010 `['', 'c:\\applications\\programming\\python_341\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip', 'C:\\applications\\programming\\python_341\\DLLs', 'C:\
\applications\\programming\\python_341\\lib', 'C:\\applications\\programming\\python_341']`

Comment: `python3.dll` exists in `"C:\applications\programming\python_341\DLLs\"`, fyi

Comment: And if you add `C:\applications\programming\python_341\DLLs` to your Windows PATH?

Comment: Added it to the path, logged out and in, ran `django-admin.py --version`. Responded with `Could not load Python dll`. I added the updated path to bottom of my question-post. Appreciate the help, @Bo102010.

Comment: If you search your drives for `django-admin.py` do you just find the one?

Comment: @Bo102010 Short answer: No. There are two. Look at the bottom of my question post.

Comment: If you run `python c:\applications\programming\python_341\Scripts\django-admin.py` things work, right? What if you run `python C:\applications\programming\python_341\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py`? DLL error?

Comment: `python C:\applications\programming\python_341\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin‌​.py startproject mysite7` actually--unexpectedly--worked properly. But if I remove the `python`, I get the dll loading error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58523/discussion-between-bo102010-and-aliteralmind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Could not load Python dll` message is coming from the [Take Command Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take_Command_Console) shell.

It seems that it doesn't respect the Windows file associations for .py files.

For future people who have this problem:

1. Try using cmd.exe instead of TCC, if you're using TCC
2. Make sure Windows has the right file associations for .py files. For Windows Vista+ try using [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/) to verify.

Comment: Can't thank you enough. Grateful for your working through this.

Comment: I opened a support thread: http://jpsoft.com/forums/threads/take-command-ignoring-my-application-extension-associations.5869/